# How can I add a condition to a WHERE clause depending on a separate table's value when given an ID for that table?

Tags: sql, select, stored-procedures, case

I am trying to make a stored procedure in SQL. I want to make a SELECT statement where a condition is added to the WHERE clause depending on a boolean value from a separate table. An ID to be used in the other table would be a parameter.

Here's an example that illustrates what I'm trying to do. Say you have two tables, one called BusinessTrip and another called Salesperson. You want to count the number of salespeople who are eligible to go on the business trip. However, some trips require the salesperson to be able to speak french. If the business trip in question requires the salesperson to speak french, then I want to add a condition in the WHERE clause that only selects salespeople who speak french. Here is what I have been trying:

```
@BusinessTrip_ID int

COUNT (salesperson_ID)
FROM   salesperson
WHERE  salesperson_isEligibleForTrip = TRUE
AND CASE WHEN (SELECT requiresFrench
               FROM   BusinessTrip
               WHERE  BusinessTrip_ID= @BusinessTrip_ID)
         THEN salesperson_canSpeakFrench = TRUE
```

My question is what can I do to accomplish what I described? How can I add a condition to a WHERE clause depending on a separate table's value when given an ID for that table as a parameter?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something as simple as;

```
SELECT COUNT(s.id)
FROM salesperson s, businesstrip b
WHERE b.id = @BusinessTrip_ID
  AND s.isEligibleForTrip
  AND (s.canSpeakFrench OR NOT b.requiresFrench)
```

- The first condition finds the trip
- The second finds all salespeople that are eligible for the trip
- The third condition sees to that either the salesperson speaks french *or* the businesstrip doesn't require french.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!